# Save Column Types of Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sqldatatypes

I have a stored procedure I plan to use for SSRS, which contains over 50 different columns. I have another procedure that executes it, and I plan to insert into a result table, but I need to know the column names before hand. When I try to execute, I get an error which states:

> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

I suspect this is because one of my columns is an incorrect data type. How can I figure out exactly what data type those columns are for creating my table?

My insert statement:

```
insert into @resultset 
   exec my_proc
```

Comment: I think you are missing a column or have an extra column - you'd get a different error message for a data type problem. What version of SQL Server are you using? Why have you tagged this `mysql`?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Currently on SQL server management studio 2008, and I'll remove the tag, meaning to say microsoft sql. Since the error isn't very detailing, how can I pull those procedure columns?

Comment: Well, the simplest way would be to look at the stored procedure, and count the columns in the final `SELECT`, and check if at least the count matches the definition of `@resultset`, and go from there. These outputs aren't really stored anywhere in SQL Server's metadata, [though there are helper functions in SQL Server 2012 that could help you when you upgrade](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2010/12/20/sql-server-v-next-denali-metadata-discovery.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a quick cheat, you could run the guts of the stored proc as a SQL statement, and change the last SELECT statement into something like:

```
SELECT TOP 0 columnlist
INTO ResultTable
FROM LastSelectStatement
```

This would give you both the correct column numbers and datatypes.

Comment: I hadn't thought of just grabbing the mass of code and making it a select. The code is long and confusing, and this seemed the best answer. Even if it is a cheat. :)